# Fatal error: Uncaught exception PAYPAL

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I got experience error when proceeding to paypal payments.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http
>   response code 400 when accessing
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\workload\third_party\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php:159
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\workload\third_party\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php(74):
>   PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\workload\third_party\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php(103):
>   PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...',
>   'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\workload\third_party\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php(303): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...',
>   'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext),
>   NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\workload\modules\member\librari in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\workload\third_party\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php
>   on line 159

Comment: I don't know the problem could be Paypal is down could be something else. No one is going to be able to help you without your code though.

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you have an error on line 159.

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255839/paypal-with-rest-php-returning-error-400

Comment: 4xx errors are client errors. Try ipn tester in paypal's sandbox to see if the ipn is working

Comment: this is the error "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.sandbox.paypal.com:443 "

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the PayPalHttpConnection Exception and print the detailed message, on why it is failing. To do so, add a try catch block around your code.

```
try {
    $creditCard->create($apiContext);
    echo $creditCard;
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getData();
}
```

Comment: thank you! I didnt know that i have to use the Exception Class otherwise it will not work

try { 
            $payment = Payment::get($paypalPaymentId, $apiContext); 
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
            die('ERROR' . $ex);            
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 $amount    = new Amount();
 $amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal($total)
    ->setDetails($details);
```

make sure your giving right currency for your account i had the same error i had set GBP and it was not working then i had put USD and it work like a charm